# css outer div for product box

Tags: css, html

Could anyone help me by describing how etc. I do to makes for a function as illustrated.

What I want is that when I mouse over a product box (have not fixed height),
I want to get a box with the buy button, etc. that looks like the picture.

Know that I do not put up the code or, but I do not know where to begin.

So if anyone has any tips or so, I'd be grateful!

[image]

Comment: if you have a try your source code please share in jsfiddle

Comment: Please share your code SO is not a code maker.

Comment: ok, will just remove all php code in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
button {
    display: none;
}
li:hover > button {
    display: block;
}

<ul>
    <li>Description 1<button>Buy</button></li>
    <li>Description 2<button>Buy</button></li>
</ul>
```

The idea here is to use the `>` operator to tell CSS to change something in our target. The target being the Buy button inside the `li` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/beautifulcoder/kj2XA/

Comment: can I get so that extra info settles over the bottom line?

Comment: Yup, simply target a `div` tag inside `li`. As long as you keep the DOM relatively flat it should work. You may have to give it a unique class name inside `li`.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** First of all: **make your items fixed size.** This prevents later issues (in layout) and allows you to create effect you described. Like:

HTML (not complete):

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
  <div class="item-content">
    <!-- item images etc here -->
  </div>
  <div class="item-actions">
    <button class="buy">Buy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .item-wrapper {
      width: 200px;
      overflow: visible;
      float: left;
      background: #999999;
      margin: 5px;
      position: relative;
      border: 2px solid #fff; /* without this you have unwanted size effects on hover*/
    }

   .item-content {
     width: 200px;
     height: 300px;
   }

   .item-actions {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background: #888;
     top:300px;
     z-index: 10;
     left: 0px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 100px;
   }
```

**2)** create javascript with jquery for your items like:

```
$('.item-wrapper').hover(function () {
    // Change css on hover .. this could be done also by changing class
    $(this).css({'border':'2px solid #880088'});
    $(this).find(".item-actions").slideDown("fast");
}, function(){
    $(this).css({'border':'2px solid #fff'});
    $(this).find(".item-actions").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h23mY/

This is also nice effect: http://jsfiddle.net/ww53e/

Comment: Hello, 
I saved this but did not get it to work.

Comment: Changed it a bit.. here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h23mY/

Comment: nice, it works fine, short question; can not do it without javascript?

Comment: yes you can but it's harder and does not work in every browser.. check css3 transitions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

lets say the item is enclosed by div tag, now use css hover on

```
<script>
//on document load item1-buy.hide(); dont forget to use jquery
</script>
<div id="item1"> 
//item goes here. 
<input type="submit" id="item1-buy" value="Buy">
</div>
```

css:

```
#item1:hover {
//here you can style how ever you want. Add orange border and so on... 
}
```

now on hover unhide the buy button using jquery #item1-buy.show();

Comment: Hello, 
How do I get it as the picture, I do not want to have a fixed height of item1

Comment: You don't need jquery to hide the element

Comment: ok try this. place another div for buy button with white background (initially hidden) once hovered show the div with postion relative and  use z-index on both item and buy div such a way that it overlaps neat and clean.

Comment: sorry it is position: absolute on buy button :)

Comment: can you post the link from which you got the screen shot?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention also use top and left css on buy button to place them on the right place. Try this and let me know how it goes.

Comment: http://www.dreamweaverclub.com/dreamweaver-show-larger-image.php

Comment: I've done the screnn shot in bhotoshop so there is no link.

Though the theme of the link has the function that I want, but I want it down, and not to the left: http://www.tonytheme.com/neocart/demo/

Comment: You have the answers in your hand, just give it a try. Just dont add those extra images on the left of the zoom effect (from the link you posted above). A quick tip use inspect element to understand what they have used to get that effect and modify it according to your need.

Comment: sorry no one is going to spoon feed here, you got to try first and post the code if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7rba/1/)

I've made a simple markup to show you the idea:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="" />
    <span>15$</span>
    <div class="buy">BUY</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.item {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
span{
    display: block;
}
.buy {
    padding: 5px;
    background: green;
    display: none;
}
.item:hover {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.item:hover .buy {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Update**: still an issue with the last image in a row, but hope it helps: [**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7rba/6/)

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="" />
    <span>15$</span>
    <div class="buy">
        <span class="button">BUY</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As danko said, mousing over moves another one of the images

Comment: Hello, 
How to get extra info to add over to the box below?

Comment: Over what box? The whole .item? Or additional (hidden) box?

Comment: yes, the boxes on the line below the box you hover

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/p7rba/7/

Comment: this works fine, however the third item on hover shoulder down to the first two?